# How to perform sum operation to 2X2 matrix in Flutter/dart

Tags: flutter, dart

in my dart code, I have a 2X2 matrix, like this

```
    List<List<int>> a = 
  [
    [10,   2],
    [2,  2],
  ];
  
      List<List<int>> b = 
  [
    [1,   2],
    [2,  2],
  ];
```

so, I want to perform sum operation to these two matrices without using any predefined function.

the result that I want, like this

```
List<List<int>> c = 
      [
        [11,   4], // 10+1   2+2
        [4,  4],   // 2+2    2+2
      ];
```

Comment: What's the reason to not use predefined functions? And what is your definition of it? Technically `+` is also a predefined function I think. At least `size()` or `add()` are. It would be quite impossible to use no functions

Comment: Why waste braincells, when you have https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/vector_math/Matrix2-class.html at your disposal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is the general answer to the sum 2D matrix

```
List<List<int>> c=[];
int minSize=a.length>b.length?b.length:a.length;

 for(int i=0;i<minSize;i++){
  List<int> temp=[];
  int minListSize=a[i].length>b[i].length?b[i].length:a[i].length;

   for(int j=0;j<minListSize;j++){
     temp.add(a[i][j]+b[i][j]);
    }
  c.add(temp);
}
```

Comment: min() is also a predefined function.

Comment: @shirshshukla sorry .. I've edited my comment

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you know beforehand they are both 2x2 matrices, then this straightforward way is a trivial solution, which I think even beats every other solution in terms of performance.

```
List<List<int>> c =
[
  [a[0][0] + b [0][0], a[0][1] + b [0][1]],
  [a[1][0] + b [1][0], a[1][1] + b [1][1]]
];
```